# jQuery Box Prob

Tags: jquery, area

I am trying to solve a rectangle problem using jQuery. Basically, I have 3 square boxes which fix inside a larger box.

I know the larger box has a max-width of 500px. I do not know what the sizes of 1, 2 or 3 will be - but I know that their aspect ratio's can change and that they must fit proportionally into the box.

How would I go about always ensuring that no matter what shape - the 3 rectangles are always proportionally sized inside the 500px box ?

Comment: Do you want them always laid out as in your examples? I.e., will b2 always be right of b1 and above b3? Even if all 3 rectangles are the same size?

Comment: @JonathanM - yeah the idea is that for 3 boxes, 1 will always be around 70% and the other 2 boxes will be smaller. The problem I am facing is that when the aspect ratios change - that is, A1 or B1 is longer or wider - I can't get A2/A3 || B2/B3 to proportionally resize inline with A1 or B1 ? A2/A3 || B2/B3 could be any size also - but they all need to fit snug and proportional ?

Comment: @David - nope :) - the height can change but should be relative to A1 or B1. That is, A2/A3 || B2/B3 should not exceed the height of A1 or B1 [which can change in height depending if it's wider or longer etc]

Comment: Ok, so at what ratio are the heights between 2 & 3 calculated? In your diagram, B2/B3 seems like 70/30 and A2/A3 50/50

Comment: @David - A1 or B1 can be any height or width [long or wide] - at which point A2/A3 || B2/B3 need to resize to be inline with it and in proportion. i.e. A1 can be longer, A2 can be longer and A3 has to resize to be in proportion to A1 etc. Likewise in B1 - if its smaller, then b2 and b3 need to increase etc

Comment: So, H1=H2+H3, and totalWidth=W1+(max(W2,W3)). Right?

Comment: Ok, so H3 = H1-H2? and H2 can be dynamic?

Comment: Seems like a good question for http://math.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: Everything's dynamic except the `totalWidth` and the aspect ratios of each rectangle.

Comment: @Andy, so W1 can **only** be 200 or 300? Your last comment is very confusing. Also, you might want to take some of the comments and edit your question to clarify the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After solving the system of equations, I believe the following is true.

> ```
> w  = Overall width (500)
> h  = Overall height
> w1 = Width of B1
> h1 = Height of B1
> w2 = Width of B2
> h2 = Height of B2
> w3 = Width of B3
> h3 = Height of B3
> a1 = Aspect ratio of B1 (width/height)
> a2 = Aspect ratio of B2 (width/height)
> a3 = Aspect ratio of B3 (width/height)
>
> w1 = (500/a2 + 500/a3) / (1/a1 + 1/a2 + 1/a3)
> ```

500 px, a1, a2, and a3 are knowns. Solve for w1, then w2, and w3. Use a1,a2, and a3 to determine h1, h2, and h3.

I believe your algorithm should be:

> ```
> 1: Find w1
> w1 = (500/a2 + 500/a3) / (1/a1 + 1/a2 + 1/a3)
>
> 2: Find w2 and w3
> w1+w2 = 500
> w1+w3 = 500
>
> 3: Determine ideal h1, h2, and h3 via aspect ratio
> h1 = w1/a1
> h2 = w2/a2
> h3 = w3/a3
>
> 4: Best-Fit h1, h2, and h3
> h = h1 = max(h2+h3, h1)
> h2 = h2 + ((h - (h2+h3))/2)
> h3 = h3 + ((h - (h2+h3))/2)
> ```

Here are the steps I followed

> ```
> Eq1: w1/a1 = h1                              [aspect ratio]                
> Eq2: h1 = (h2 + h3)                          [see diagram]
> Eq3: h2 = w2/a2                              [aspect ratio]  
> Eq4: h3 = w3/a3                              [aspect ratio]  
> Eq5: w2 = 500 - w1                           [see diagram]
> Eq6: w3 = 500 - w1                           [see diagram]
>
> w1/a1 = h1                                   [Eq1]
> w1/a1 = (h2 + h3)                            [Eq2]
> w1/a1 = (w2/a2 + w3/a3)                      [Eq3, Eq4]
> w1/a1 = ((500 - w1)/a2 + (500 - w1)/a3)      [Eq5, Eq6]
>
> w1/a1 = 500/a2 - w1/a2 + 500/a3 - w1/a3
> w1/a1 + w1/a2 + w1/a3 = 500/a2 + 500/a3 
> w1 * (1/a1 + 1/a2 + 1/a3) = 500/a2 + 500/a3 
> w1 = (500/a2 + 500/a3) / (1/a1 + 1/a2 + 1/a3)
> ```

Comment: thanks i'll try it however can you extrapolate on h1, h2, h3 ?

Comment: I cannot even remotely understand what you did there — have an upvote!

Comment: Back in high school or junior high when you were sitting in Algebra I, and some kid asked "When, in real life, am I EVER going to use this?" Well, today is the day.